# String Where condition in SQLite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm working on an Android application and I want to have **two** separate strings in the `WHERE` condition in my SQL query.

This is my code:

```
       String query=" SELECT * FROM "+USER_TABLE+" where Username=? COLLATE NOCASE and Password=?";
    Cursor logincursor=   database.rawQuery(query, new String[]{username,password})
if (logincursor.moveToFirst()) {

            user.UserName = logincursor.getString(logincursor
                    .getColumnIndex("Username"));
            user.Password =new EncryptDecrypt().decrypt(logincursor.getString(logincursor
                    .getColumnIndex("Password")));
            user.FullName = logincursor.getString(logincursor
                    .getColumnIndex("Fullname"));
            user.UserID = logincursor.getInt(logincursor
                    .getColumnIndex("UserID"));
            user.EmployeeID = logincursor.getInt(logincursor
                    .getColumnIndex("EmployeeID"));

        }
```

Please suggest a good method to accomplish this in my Android app.

Comment: I am not getting any values from my app when i use String as where condition

Comment: Consider adding relevant code to the question. Nothing wrong with the SQL you've posted.

Comment: @laalto I have changed my question as per your comment...

Comment: There's still little that demonstrates the problem. At least you're not using the `Cursor` return value from `rawQuery()` though.

Comment: @Arun Please check my edited answer. Please try second query and try to print logincursor.getCount() method return value.

Comment: If you don't get any data, the `where` condition doesn't match any rows... There's still a little actual information to reproduce the problem (for example, sample data and params). However, the password looks suspicious as it seems to be encrypted in database and likely it's not encrypted when passed to the query.

Comment: @laalto..Thanks for the advice. There was another mistake. I had inserted a small white space along with my user name. Any ways Thanks for you reminder

Answer (score 0):

Use below query.

```
db.rawQuery("select * from login_table where username =" + "\""+ username.trim() + "\""+" and password="+ "\""+ password.trim() + "\""+, null);
```

**OR**

```
db.query(USER_TABLE,  new String[] {"*"}," Username = ? and Password =?", new String[]{username,password}, null, null, null);
```

Comment: what if username is `" OR 1=1;` :)